# WiFi disabled by hard switch

Tags: wireless

My WiFi is disabled.

I have an asus r704v laptop and there is no hardware switch to turn WiFi on/off, thus I cannot go online using WiFi.

The driver is the correct one for the realtrek card. How do I switch my WiFi on?

Comment: Some notebooks (I am not sure about yours) have internal WiFi switch that can be flipped by Window$ drivers. In this case, if you set WiFi off in Window$, you can't use it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Wifi adapter is blocked. you can unblock your WiFi adapter by using **sudo rfkill unblock all** command in Terminal (use Ctrl+Alt+T to open).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Ubuntu issue.
This is not any driver issue.
This is caused by me (and possibly you).

While watching some video... I tried to increase volume with:
`Fn + F10` key combination ... But I mistakenly pressed
`Fn + F12` which was `Wifi button` with 'Radio' symbol on it, which disabled my wifi connection.

Running below command in Terminal, you can see the issue:

```
> rfkill list all

0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth           #or whatever it is
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes    `<------ that's because I press Wifi button (above) mistakenly
```

**Solution**: Press again the `Fn + F12` (or, some other key where you have Radio symbol)

Now run again the same command:

```
> rfkill list all

    0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth           #or whatever it is
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

    <------ no means solved.
```

Now, go to:

> (Windows button, if you have on the keyboard) > Settings > Wifi > move
> to On > select your Wiki connection to enter credentials

Done, your internet is back on.

Reference = [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507631)

I hope this works ...